# Angular v12 Component style files not compiling tailwindcss @apply

Tags: angular, sass, tailwind-css, angular-library

I am a student in computer science and I am working on a project for my studies. I currently try to develop a component library for the Angular framework using Angular V12. For styling I want to use Tailwindcss (especially because it spares me with working with media queries on some points...). Anyway, when I build the library and test it in another project, no tailwind styles are included.

I know from the tailwind docs, that you can use some directives or functions like @apply in plain scss.

To give you a better understanding on the problem I have linked the github repo to the library's source code for reference.
I have a button component which should have some tailwind styles applied. This is done by specifying a class to the html element called `.btn`. This class is defined inside the `button.component.scss` file. This file is as well referenced in the `button.component.ts` file as styleUrl.
So my question is: How can I fix the issue with the styles not being applied using `@apply` inside `button.component.scss`?

This is how the styles are defined in `button.component.scss`:

```
.btn {
  @apply px-2 py-1 text-sm rounded-sm transition-all bg-placeholder-light hover:bg-placeholder active:bg-placeholder-dark relative border-2 border-transparent;
}
```

This `.btn` class is then applied to the html element like this:

```html
<button class="btn" (click)="clicked($event)">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</button>
```

Exporting this does not apply the classes defined previously.
Howevery, if I directly apply the styles in the class attribute like that:

```html
<button class="px-2 py-1 text-sm rounded-sm transition-all bg-placeholder-light hover:bg-placeholder active:bg-placeholder-dark relative border-2 border-transparent" (click)="clicked($event)">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</button>
```

Everything works as expected. This seems like a very strange behaviour as I am expecting the  `button.component.scss` file to be somehow compiled with the correct styles.

Is there a way to fix this problem? Or do I have to take a very different approach?
I know that I could simply apply the styles like in my last example, but I want to give developers the option to add classes like `btn-primary` (which adds additional styles).

I thank everyone in advance for taking their time to look into my problem. Hopefully someone can assist me with that problem.

Hope you have a great day!

PS: The link to the repo: https://github.com/z3ttee/alliance-ngx/tree/issue/tailwind/projects/alliance-ngx (you may want to use the branch issue/tailwind)

Comment: I'm trying to solve this as well, did you find a solution at the end ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, let's say the component you publish is called `ui-components`.

Modify your tailwind config on the parent project (the one using your component) to have something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.html', './src/**/*.ts', './node_modules/ui-components/**/*.{html,ts,js}'],
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
  corePlugins: {
  },
};
```